# RestAPI using .net 4.5

Tags: json, wcf

I have created one WCF application using .net framework 4.5 . I  needs to call the WCF method & update the response accordingly in another MVC Application

Kindly Help me for the same

Below is my Service Contract

```
 public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke (Method ="GET",ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "CBSResponse/{refno}/{amount}/{draccno}/{craccno}/{appid}")]
        Posting_Result GetCBSResponse(string refno, string amount, string draccno, string craccno, string appid);



        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class Posting_Result
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime modifieddt { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is my Code in Controller

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


            string url = obj.payment_url + obj.refno + "//" + obj.total.ToString() + "//" +obj.draccno + "//" + obj.craccno + "//Subh";
            HttpResponseMessage wcfResponse = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            HttpContent stream = wcfResponse.Content;
            var data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // var paymentRequest = Request.Content.ReadAsAsync<PaymentRequest>().Result;
            var result = data.Result;
```

I am getting below response in result variable

**{"GetCBSResponseResult":{"modifieddt":"/Date(1466838186130+0530)/","remarks":"","status":"S"}}**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution

I changed my service contract to produce JSON instead of XML.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "CBSResponse/{refno}/{amount}/{draccno}/{craccno}/{appid}")]
        Posting_Result GetCBSResponse(string refno, string amount, string draccno, string craccno, string appid);
```

On the client side, I used below code

```
var result = wcfResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var myclass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
            CBS_Response user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CBS_Response>(result);
```

Comment: Also added class (CBS_Response) with members same as JSON